# Enable button When any of the RadioButton selected in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Want to enable my Button when any Of the radioButton checked, but my code didn't work

```
protected void Rb1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (rb1.Checked  || rb2.Checked )
    {
        btnCheckOut.Enabled = true;
    }


}
```

Comment: make sure `AUTOPOSTBACK` property of the radio buttons are set to `TRUE`

Comment: Can you show us the relevant section(s) of your ASPX markup?

Comment: Thanks it works..  autoPostBack was not true

Answer (score 1):

Please check your component names are correctly spelled. Are you sure it's `rb1` and not `Rb1`?

```
protected void Rb1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (Rb1.Checked || Rb2.Checked ) { btnCheckOut.Enabled = true; } }
```

Comment: It's rb1 and rb2